# Schema.org 'Organization' only on contact page or on every page?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I'd like to place a Schema.org `Organization` item on my website.

Should I place the JSON-LD only on the contact page or can I add it to every page of the website? What is the best solution?

Comment: Related: [Proper use of Schema.org “WebSite” type: apply it to all pages or just the home page?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31350171/1591669) · [“Organization” for homepage, but which types for the other pages?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/92463/17633)

Answer (score 4):

With Schema.org, you would typically provide structured data about what is relevant to the current page.

Assuming that it’s the website of the organization, you could specify your `Organization` as value for these properties:

- [**`publisher`**](http://schema.org/publisher)
  (for `WebSite`, for every `WebPage`)
- [**`about`**](http://schema.org/about)  and [**`mainEntity`**](http://schema.org/mainEntity)
  (for `WebSite`, for the `WebPage` on the homepage, for the `AboutPage`)
- [**`author`**](http://schema.org/author)
  (for `Article`, `BlogPosting` etc.)

(There are more properties, of course. Simply check the type pages for properties that have `Organization`, or the parent type `Thing`, as "Expected Type".)

Note that you don’t have to repeat the data, you could simply [refer to it instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41067598/1591669). Then it would make sense to provide the full data on the page that is given as `url` of the `Organization`, so typically the homepage.

Answer (score 3):

According to Google, Organization Schema should be on only 1 page of a website (usually the homepage of contact page).

Source: https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-do-not-put-organization-schema-markup-on-every-page/289981/