# Correct deployment of structured data for Google rich cards

Tags: javascript, seo, google-search, google-rich-snippets

I am confused as to the correct inclusion of structured data, primarily for google rich media.

---

**1. Must/should every page have it's own json, or should the root page contain the json for all pages?**

---

**2. The structured data is essentially JavaScript. Does it have to be inline, or can it be in another file?**

---

**3. A normal browser might waste time with big structured data JavaScript - information which is irrelevant to it. Is there a good solution/best practice for dealing with this?**

Comment: Your 1. question might be answered here: [Proper use of Schema.org “WebSite” type: apply it to all pages or just the home page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31350171/1591669) ··· Your 2. question is answered here: [How to move JSON-LD from in-line to in-a-file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33236198/1591669)  (note that JSON-LD in a `script` element is not JavaScript) -- and this answers the 3. question, too, I guess. ··· If something is unclear, please [edit] your question post and provide details -- and make it about *one* question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, these questions answer my problems. The problems with those existing questions is that I found none of them because they focus on specific aspects of my main question: How to deploy structured data for google correctly. I feel like there is one question - the title - and the other "questions" are aspects which I thought necessary to answer the main question, I would be delighted if you made your comment an answer so i could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, it should. Structured data is based on the URI paradigm. It means, the unique ID of the document is its URL. So yes, your structured data belongs always to certain URL.
2. No, it isn't. JSON-LD is not a javascript, even thought it is implemented with the `<script>` - but it isn't a javascript. And no, it can't be in another file.
3. Not, it doesn't. Browser don't interpret JSON-LD scripts - they don't need it, this information is not for them and it isn't relevant for the browser's job, which is page rendering. JSON-LD scripts can indeed be placed on the bottom of the HTML source code - but you will not realize any acceleration impact by this.